# Lubuntu 17.10 - paired blutooth headphones successfuly, but can't connect to it

Tags: sound, lubuntu, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

So I am new to linux and I managed to pair them successfuly, however when I try to connect to it - it says the following: ''connection failed - use the audio menu to connect to this device''.

When I go into PulseAudio(audio menu), it doesn't show me my headphones as a viable output option. Under Port is says: ''Speakers'' or ''Headphones (unplugged)'' but when I choose Headphones, the sound just goes away completely.

(So I guess that would be the option for when I use my headphones with a cable.)

But I can't seem to connect to my headphones and I have already tried reinstalling bluez.

Other questions talk about how the headphones aren't detected or not being able to pair, but my problem is a bit different. I hope you can help or point me in the right direction.

Much love, Pseu - a real one.

EDIT: bro I have no idea what you mean by allowing ''pactl list short | grep blue''..... so ok I allow it bruv?

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `pactl list short | grep blue`

Comment: how do i do that??

Comment: Open a terminal CTRL + ALT + t and paste the command in, then press enter

Comment: nothing happened when I did that... what do I do now?

Answer (score 8):

If you can pair the device but it does not show up as a separate sound source in sound settings (ie paired but not connected), or if you are getting the 'use the audio menu' warning, you need to use the CLI bluethoothctl tool to connect.

After pairing your device using the LXPanel applet, go to the terminal and run this command:

```
bluetoothctl
```

Now type

```
devices
```

and press enter. A list of paired Bluetooth devices will be shown. Copy the MAC address next to device you want to connect to. Something like 00:1B:DC:2A:82:30
Now type

```
connect 00:1B:DC:2A:82:30
```

and replace the MAC address with yours. If successful, type

```
exit
```

And press enter. You should now see your audio device in the sound settings.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

If that dosen't work then:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-bluetooth
```

and then do:

```
killall pulseaudio
reboot
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.nielsvandermolen.com/bluetooth-headphones-ubuntu/

hi try this, it works perfectly, and the guy has explained the reasons clearly too.

To summarize:

step 1 : you would need pulseaudio and blueman , and pulseaudio-module-bluetooth

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio blueman pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

step 2 : connect your headset with pulseaudio, using bluetoothctl or gui.

step 3 : manually activate bluetooth discover module (step 4 makes this step automatic. I emphasize this step because it is the one that was giving me problem as it seemed the bluetooth discover module never gets auto activated even when all the packages were installed)

```
sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

step 4 : (lets make step 3 happen automatic)

edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` using text editor with root privilege, and comment out the `ifexists` clauses from the file that matches the section below :

```
sudo vim /etc/pulse/default.pa

### Automatically load driver modules for Bluetooth hardware 
#.ifexists module-bluetooth-policy.so ---> // comment this line
    load-module module-bluetooth-policy     
#.endif   //-->comment this line

#.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so  -->//comment this line
    load-module module-bluetooth-discover
#.endif --->//comment this line`
```

step 5) kill the pulseaudio and restart

```
sudo pulseaudio --k
sudo pulseaudio  --start
```

or reboot system if step 6 does not work, and retry step 6 after reboot.

step 6) Now open bluetooth manager (in lubuntu its in preferences !!)  and there you should see your headset. If no device, you need to connect using pulseaudio again. Right-click your device --> setup --> handsfree (worked for me).

If lucky, there should now be headphone(plugged in) option in sound settings--> output devices.